# What formula would be used to return a range of numbers before and after a single value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have: "14.88".
In an adjacent cell, I would like to return a range of: "10-15"
Is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Please (1) define clearly and explicitly what result you want for what input, and (2) try to solve this yourself, and show us what you tried.

Comment: (3) add source data example and the result for is.

Comment: If you want to obtain the including range with start=0 and step=5, then decide what does you want to obtain when the value is on the boundary (for example, 10.00)...

Comment: Go to the adjacent cell and type "10-15".  If you want a more general solution, give us more detail about the requirements.

Comment: Did the units for the range is 5? For example I have value "1.1", did the range is 0-5?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=FLOOR.MATH(A1,5)&"-"&CEILING.MATH(A1,5)
```

Or this, if you're using Office 2007 or older:

```
=FLOOR(A1,5)&"-"&CEILING(A1,5)
```

This assumes the data is in `A1`.

---

**Edit**

Like @Akina has pointed out, the formula needs to consider the boundary cases, too. So, if you want to place `10` in the `10-15` range, use this:

```
=FLOOR.MATH(A1,5)&"-"&CEILING.MATH(A1,5)+5
```

Or this, if you want it to place in the `5-10` range:

```
=FLOOR.MATH(A1,5)-5&"-"&CEILING.MATH(A1,5)
```

Comment: It's working & returns `10-15` ☺ +10

Comment: Nice. Tried it at work (Excel 2010) and neither `FLOOR.MATH` nor `CEILING.MATH` are present in this version.